# Is there any way to get the current record count in a HTML table that's using jQuery datatable plugin

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I tried using this:

```
 var rowCount = $('#locationsTable tbody tr').length - 1;
```

But the one issue is that you can't tell if there is 1 record in the table or 0 records because, when there are 0 records, the jQuery datatable plugin shows one extra `tr` row that says "No records matched".

Is there a better way to get actual valid row/record count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
    alert( oSettings.fnRecordsTotal() );
    alert( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() );
    alert( oSettings.fnDisplayEnd() );

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rely on the specific class of the "no records matched" cell:

```
// Detect empty cell
if ($('#locationsTable .dataTables_empty').length > 0) return 0;

// Otherwise, count cells
return $('#locationsTable > tbody > tr').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

there's a new DataTables API since these answers were published.

I used this tonight:

> var results = oTable.page.info().recordsDisplay;

source: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you selector would be slightly more efficient like this:

```
$('#locationsTable>tbody>tr')
```

Then enhance you code with a custom selector:

```
var rowCount = $('#locationsTable>tbody>tr:excludeNoRecordsMatched').length - 1;
```

The code for which is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        excludeNoRecordsMatched: function(el) {
            return ($(el).text().indexOf('No records matched') >= 0);
        },
    });
});
```

Untested, but might work. You could certainly use something like this anyway!

Comment: thanks for the try..  rowcount seems to be working when there are no records but if there are records i am getting -1 for the var rowCount

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is with the following code which actually gives you the number of records in the data array and not the number of rows in the HTML table which is what your code is doing.:

```
var oTable = $('#primarytable').dataTable();
oTable.fnDeleteRow(oTable.fnGetPosition(row));
$("#currenttablecount").html(oTable.fnGetData().length);
```